# Dicom Registration - IPP and PS

Tags: alignment, dicom, image-registration

I have two dicom files with the following Image Patient Position (IPP) and Pixel Spacing (PS)

**img1, has PS of 2mm  IPP of (-256,-256,-128)**

**img2 has PS of 2.5mm and IPP of (-206,-201,-128)**

For **image restration / alignment**, I understand I need to have both images
with the same PS and IPP

My first step is to bring img1 to PS of 2.5mm i.e. interpolate
**img1 by 1.25 (2.5/2) times** to match that of img2.

```
**Pixel Spacing Calculation:**

2mm = 1pixel

2.5mm = 1/2 *2.5 = 1.25pixel
```

Do this mean that the **IPP of img1 will also change to (-320,-320,-128)**
i.e. by 1.25 (-256*1.25) times as well?

Thanks a lot in advance

Ash

Answer (score 0):

No, the IPP defines the position of middle of the top left pixel of the image in **patient/world coordinates**. You might need to apply the scaling to the position to achieve sub-pixel accuracy.